# Ansible azure_rm_deployment referencing parameters from 2 locations

Tags: json, azure, parameters, ansible

I have an Azure RM template (`WindowsVirtualMachine.json` and `WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json`) that I can deploy via Ansible with the following YML:

```
---
- name: Deploy Azure ARM template.
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Create Azure Deploy
      azure_rm_deployment:
        state: present
        resource_group_name: AnsibleTest
        location: UK South
        template: "{{ lookup('file', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.json') }}"
        parameters: "{{ (lookup('file', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json') | from_json).parameters }}"
```

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to reference 2 parameter locations; 1 from the JSON and another from within the Ansible YML file. Such as:

```
template: "{{ lookup('file', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.json') }}"
parameters: "{{ (lookup('file', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json') | from_json).parameters }}"
  adminPassword: 
    value: "Password123"
```

The reason I ask is the enquiry if I could then put the `adminPassword` value inside of Ansible Vault, hidden from prying eyes.

I'm new to coding and sadly Google isn't bringing me any joy. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>i doubt that can be done directly, but you can, probably read file into a variable and modify its contents directly in the variable and pass it to the deployment</strike>. Check the proper answer by Techraf ;)

That being sad, there are other ways of achieving something similar to what you are asking, like Azure Key Vault or using deployment "constants" (which probably doesnt work in this case, but who knows) or you could generate the password on the fly, that way you don't need to worry about securing it.

Comment: I ended up using the Azure Key Vault, it seems to work nicely for what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Save the password into an Ansible Vault-protected variable, for example `adminPassword_defined_in_vault`
2. Turn the parameters file into a template, i.e. rename it to `WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json.j2`
3. Modify the above template, so it contains:

   ```
   "adminPassword": {
       "value": "{{ adminPassword_defined_in_vault }}"
   },
   ```
4. In the playbook use `template` lookup plugin instead of `file`:

   ```
   parameters: "{{ (lookup('template', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json.j2')).parameters }}"
   ```

Comment: @techraf By "Save the password into an Ansible Vault-protected variable,
 **(adminPassword_defined_in_vault)**" do I need the brackets () or would this be OK?
**adminPassword_defined_in_vault: "Password123"**

At the moment it's failing with:
_fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ (lookup('template', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json.j2') | from_json).parameters }}): expected string or buffer"
}_

Comment: No, brackets were a part of the explanation as indicated by formatting. I made it clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately this has not worked for me, so I resorted to using an Azure Key Vault instead.

Comment: @Beefcake Just remove `from_json` filter from the line. Seems not required for `template` lookup results.